# How do I convert a Visual Studio 2010 database project to an SSDT Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a clean install of windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 Premium inc. SP 1. I also just installed the developer edition of SQL Server 2012 .

I now should be able to convert the Visual Studio 2010 database project to an SSDT project. According to [this technet blogpost](http://blogs.technet.com/b/gdcomdbbi/archive/2012/03/22/convert-visual-studio-2010-database-project-to-ssdt-project.aspx) it should be as easy as opening my Visual Studio solution file and follow the conversion wizard. The problem is that the conversion wizard never appears. Also, the "Convert to SQL Server Database project..." context menu item does not exist when right clicking on the VS 2010 database project.

I'm probably missing something in my SQL 2012 installation. The question is: what?

My SQL 2012 install configuration:
[image: My SQL 2012 install configuration]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem. Apparently I still needed to download SSDT standalone from [http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). Althought SQL Server Data Tools is listed in the screenshot above.

EDIT: Updated the link. Thanks @ryanwebjackson

Comment: what version of SQL data tools did you have installed before and after?

Comment: The link appears to be broken. Also, as far as I can tell, there isn't a current stand-alone version of SSDT (see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt).

Answer (score 15):

In case it helps someone else.

In my case I did not get a wizard of any kind, even though I did ALL necessary installs.

Symptoms:

- Open solution in VS2012.
- Database project is unloaded, it says it needs migration.
- Reload database project, it says it requires functional changes (or something like it). I press OK.
- Database project is available, it builds, but when I close VS2012, and re-open the solution, it says the same thing over and over again.

Solution:

- Unknown to me VS2012 does create a new project of ssdt type. Unfortunately it doesn't load it. I have a project .dbproj file and a project .sqlproj file. The .dbproj file is loaded.
- Remove the database project from the solution.
- Add existing project -> select the .sqlproj file. The database project is loaded again. It builds.

Now everything seems well, I can open and build the solution in VS2012 without any problems. Also, I can reopen the solution in VS2010SP1, and it opens and builds without any problems.

Comment: i only have a .sqlproj file in my solution (I don't see any .dbproj).  is there some file i need to delete or do i just need to remove and re-add the project?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a situation where you're trying to migrate from .dbproj created for Visual Studio 2008 to .sqlproj for Visual Studio 2012 you might run into same behavior (no wizzard, can't load project).

In my case there was even quite absurd situation where Visual Studio 2012 created .sqlproj file and copied into it the contents of old Visual Studio 2008 .dbproj.

None of the proposed workarounds helped, I had to **first convert from 2008 .dbproj to 2010 .dbproj** (using Visual Studio 2010) and **then from 2010 .dbproj to .sqlproj** (using Visual Studio 2012).

Answer (score 0):

For me something diffrent works.

After migration you will have both *.dbproj and *.sqlproj in project directory.
Just remove project (dbproj and attach existing sqlproj project).

Do not know why solution file is not updated.